# Trying to navigate between screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am having an issue trying to grasp navigation on react native when it involves from what it looks like three components deeps. Long story short I am trying to navigate from my login screen using a button to navigate to my signup screen and I think I botched this bad.

So far I put a navigation container in my Apps.tsx file

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import LandingPage from './screens/LandingPage';
// import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import SignUpForm from './screens/SignUpForm';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import ImageComp from './components/ImageComp';


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});



export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={LandingPage} />
        <Stack.Screen name='Sign_Up' component={SignUpForm} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Next I have my landing page screen setup with the LoginForm component that contains the button to create an account that should send me to account page.

```
import LoginForm from '../components/LoginForm'
import ImageComp from '../components/ImageComp'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity,TextInput, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import { Formik } from 'formik'
import * as yup from 'yup'
import SignUpForm from './SignUpForm';


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });



const LandingPage = () =>{
    return(
            
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ImageComp />
            <LoginForm />
        </View>
    )
}

export default LandingPage
```

Then lastly I have my login form that has the create button at the bottom which should just take me to the create account screen.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity,TextInput, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import { Formik } from 'formik'
import * as yup from 'yup'
import SignUpForm from '../screens/SignUpForm';


const loginValidationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
    .string()
    .email("Please enter valid email")
    .required('Email Address is Required'),
  password: yup
    .string()
    .min(8, ({ min }) => `Password must be at least ${min} characters`)
    .required('Password is required'),
})

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 20,
        width: 350

    },
    loginHeader: {
        fontSize: 25,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        padding: 25,
        
    },
    labelText:{
        marginTop: 20
    },

    loginBorder:{
      borderLeftWidth: 1,
      borderRightWidth: 1,
      borderTopWidth: 1,
      borderBottomWidth: 1,
      height: 30,
      borderRadius: 5,
      
      
    },
    loginBtn: {
      backgroundColor: '#0267C1',
      textAlign: 'center',
      margin: 20,
      padding: 10,
      borderRadius: 10,
    
     
      
    },

    createBtn: {
        backgroundColor: '#F87575',
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 20,
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 10,
        
      },

      btnText:{
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: "#FFFFFF"
      },
      errors:{
        fontSize: 15, 
        color: 'red' 
      }
})


const LoginForm = () =>{

    

    
    return(
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    {/* Formik is a custom library for the pourpose of forms validation, etc. */}
    <Formik 
    validationSchema={loginValidationSchema}
    initialValues={{email: '', password:''}} 
    onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}>
      {({handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values, errors,
     isValid})=>(
      <>
      <Text>Email</Text>
      <TextInput 
      name='email' 
      onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
      onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
      value={values.email}
      keyboardType="email-address"
      style={styles.loginBorder}/>
      {errors.email ?
         <Text style={styles.errors}>{errors.email}</Text> : <Text></Text>
       }

      <Text style={styles.labelText}>Password</Text>
      <TextInput name='password' 
        onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
        onBlur={handleBlur('password')}
        value={values.password}
        secureTextEntry={true} style={styles.loginBorder}
      />
      {errors.password ?
         <Text style={styles.errors}>{errors.password}</Text> : <Text></Text>
       }
      <Text>Forget Password?</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginBtn} onPress={handleSubmit}  disabled={!isValid}>
        <Text style={styles.btnText}>Login</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </>
      )}
    </Formik>
      
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.createBtn}>
        <Text style={styles.btnText} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Sign_Up')}>Create Account</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default LoginForm
```

My question is, how do I wire this part to navigate from the login screen to the create account screen by the button on the bottom of the screen?

Comment: I see that in your route stack, the route is named `Sign_Up`, but in your `onPress` handler, you try to navigate to `Sign UP` (no underscore, wrong casing.)  Try fixing that first?

Comment: @MattMorgan I just fixed that so far, now it's just a dead button. It's not firing off any errors so far

Comment: Nevermind it was pointing at that onPress attribute in the button. I had to get rid of that for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

yout have two mistake:

-first

in component you want to navigate import it as prop in component then use it:

```
const LoginForm = ({navigation}) =>{
```

-second

you put onPress on Text Component instead of TouchableOpacity

Comment: This didn't work out. The thing to consider is I was drilling which I didn't intend on initally. I ended up moving login form in to the landing page since it was not a big change. I will be renaming some stuff in the process.